# Regexp arabic text paragraph

Tags: qt, arabic, qstring, qregexp

Given string:

```
QString unformatted =
   "Some non arabic text"
   "بعض النصوص العربية"
   "Another non arabic text"
   "النص العربي آخر";
```

How to reach following result using `QRegExp` or other way:

```
"<p>Some non arabic text</p>"
"<p dir='rtl'>بعض النصوص العربية</p>"
"<p>Another non arabic text</p>"
"<p dir='rtl'>النص العربي آخر</p>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: The QRegExp class provides pattern matching using regular expressions. A regular expression, or "regexp", is a pattern for matching substrings in a text.

Comment: This is useful in many contexts, e.g.,Validation:A regexp can test whether a substring meets some criteria, e.g. is an integer or contains no whitespace. Searching:A regexp provides more powerful pattern matching than simple substring matching, e.g., match one of the words mail, letter or correspondence, but none of the words email, mailman, mailer, letterbox, etc.

Comment: Search and Replace: A regexp can replace all occurrences of a substring with a different substring, e.g., replace all occurrences of & with &amp; except where the & is already followed by an amp;. String Splitting: A regexp can be used to identify where a string should be split apart, e.g. splitting tab-delimited strings.

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html

Comment: Search [non arabic block] and replace with <p>[non arabic block]</p>, and search [arabic block] and replace with <p dir='rtl'>[arabic block]</p>. Is it possible or not?

Comment: try with my solution

Comment: Those string literals may not contain what you think they do -- always wrap them in the [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) macro to ensure compatibility with Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function to separate by arabic expressions:

```
QString split_arabic(QString text){
    QRegExp rx("[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF][ \u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]+");
    int pos = 0;


    QStringList list;

    while ((pos = rx.indexIn(text, pos)) != -1) {
        list << rx.cap(0);
        pos += rx.matchedLength();
    }

    for(int i=0; i < list.length(); i++){
        QString str = list.at(i);
        text.replace(str, "<p dir='rtl'>"+str+"</p>");
    }

    return text;
}
```

Example:

```
QString unformatted =
            "Some non arabic text"
            "بعض النصوص العربية"
            "Another non arabic text"
            "النص العربي آخر";


qDebug()<<unformatted;
qDebug()<<split_arabic(unformatted);
```

Output:

```
"Some non arabic textبعض النصوص العربيةAnother non arabic textالنص العربي آخر"
"Some non arabic text<p dir='rtl'>بعض النصوص العربية</p>Another non arabic text<p dir='rtl'>النص العربي آخر</p>"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyllanesc!